# Intermittent iPad app crash using Swift

Tags: crash, ios8, grand-central-dispatch, stack-trace, multipeer-connectivity

I have been seeing the following crash intermittently in my app. Following is the crash log for the crash. I am not able to figure out the cause for this crash. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with the reason behind this crash.

CRASHLOG:

> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
>   Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe
>   Triggered by Thread:  5

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34515648 syscall_thread_switch + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x345a2646 _OSSpinLockLockSlow$VARIANT$mp + 42
2   CFNetwork                       0x25df2f7e _BrowserCancel(__CFNetServiceBrowser*) + 22
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2631f804 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2631ec16 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 218
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2631d294 __CFRunLoopRun + 764
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2626adac CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
7   CoreFoundation                  0x2626abbe CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
8   GraphicsServices                0x2d5dc04c GSEventRunModal + 132
9   UIKit                           0x29836a2c UIApplicationMain + 1436
10  Xavier                          0x000c85c4 0x6c000 + 378308
11  Xavier                          0x000c8720 0x6c000 + 378656
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x34463aac start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x345152c8 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x34437ec4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 276
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x34437bf6 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3452908c __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2632354e __CFSocketManager + 486
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7e64 _pthread_body + 136
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7dd6 _pthread_start + 114
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34515518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3451530c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2631edc6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2631d38c __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2626adac CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2626abbe CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   CFNetwork                       0x25e231fa +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] +   482
7   Foundation                      0x270671b6 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7e64 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7dd6 _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34515518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3451530c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2631edc6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2631d38c __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2626adac CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x262b46c6 CFRunLoopRun + 94
6   CoreMotion                      0x26b6bb7a 0x26b2d000 + 256890
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7e64 _pthread_body + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7dd6 _pthread_start + 114
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.MCSession.callbackQueue
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0049b69c 0x304000 + 1668764
1   Xavier                          0x000d4af8 0x6c000 + 428792
2   Xavier                          0x000d5008 0x6c000 + 430088
3   MultipeerConnectivity           0x2824ba26 __58-[MCSession syncHandleNetworkEvent:pid:freeEventWhenDone:]_block_invoke617 + 114
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x34428610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x34432714 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 944
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x344321e4 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 80
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x34434156 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 310
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3443527a _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 102
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5e22 _pthread_wqthread + 666
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5b74 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x345299cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5e9c _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5b74 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x345299cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5e9c _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5b74 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x345299cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5e9c _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5b74 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x345299cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5e9c _pthread_wqthread + 788
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5b74 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.gamekitservices.gcksession.recvproc
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3452908c __select + 20
1   MultipeerConnectivity           0x2825f8cc gckSessionRecvProc + 5252
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7e64 _pthread_body + 136
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7dd6 _pthread_start + 114
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.gamekitservices.gcksession.sendproc
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3452908c __select + 20
1   MultipeerConnectivity           0x2825fe68 gckSessionSendProc + 268
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7e64 _pthread_body + 136
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7dd6 _pthread_start + 114
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  com.apple.gamekitservices.eventcallback.eventcbproc
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34528b38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a73dc _pthread_cond_wait + 516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a82ac pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   MultipeerConnectivity           0x28279a4c EventCBProc + 76
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7e64 _pthread_body + 136
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7dd6 _pthread_start + 114
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34528b38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7416 _pthread_cond_wait + 574
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a71d0 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 12
3   MultipeerConnectivity           0x2825de5c gckSessionRecvUDPPacketWithTimeout + 252
4   ICE                             0x2d297234 ICERecvUDPPacketWithTimeout + 340
5   ICE                             0x2d29eed2 RecvAndProcess + 310
6   ICE                             0x2d2a2d1e ConnectivityCheckProc + 894
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7e64 _pthread_body + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a7dd6 _pthread_start + 114
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x345a5b80 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x29f6be18      r2: 0x34e7b7e4      r3: 0x00000000
r4: 0x17de21f0    r5: 0x2d34620a      r6: 0x17de60d0      r7: 0x00852bc8
r8: 0x17de60d0    r9: 0x18a6a4c0     r10: 0x36c40660     r11: 0x00000000
ip: 0x33ee2531    sp: 0x00852bc4      lr: 0x33ee25c3      pc: 0x0049b69c
cpsr: 0x60000030
```

My breakpoint hits this line before it crashes:

```
let rootVC: UINavigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController as UINavigationController
```

Following is the whole method that contains this line:

```
     func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!) {

    //Check to see what kind of data is received
    var dataReceived:AnyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)!;

    if let newData = dataReceived as? String {
        let rootVC: UINavigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController as UINavigationController;
        let topVC = rootVC.topViewController;

        if let block = self.commandResolver[newData] {
            block(topVC);
            return;
        } else {
            println("Command resolver returns nil block");
        }
    } else if let newData = dataReceived as? NSDictionary {
        let rootVC: UINavigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController as UINavigationController;
         let topVC = rootVC.topViewController as ViewController;
         topVC.connected(true, withGroupName: newData["GroupName"] as String!);
    } else {
        println("Data is not a String");
    }
}
```

My window.rootViewController is UINavigationController so it should not be nil if that is the problem. Can it be though?

I would really appreciate your help guys.

Comment: Did you fix this crash? Thank you!

Comment: @PabloMartinez- No I ended up not using Multipeer Connectivity at all for my project

Comment: Oh good to know! Could you please me say which platform did you use for this? Thanks!

Comment: @PabloMartinez I ended up using low level socket programming

Answer (score 1):

It's crashing in a background thread inside this block:

```
3   MultipeerConnectivity           0x2824ba26 __58-[MCSession syncHandleNetworkEvent:pid:freeEventWhenDone:]_block_invoke617 + 114
```

UIKit is generally not thread-safe and is "Main Thread only", so the fact that calling `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController` from a background thread crashes is not surprising. You probably want to dispatch this whole block back to the main thread.